# Terraform tries to reorder and recreate config block in a loop every time one is added

Tags: terraform

I'm seeing some weird behaviour when I modify config blocks in a loop.

It looks like Terraform is resorting the config blocks or something:

```
// example map
variable "my_apps" {
  type = map(object({
    app-type-1 = list(string)
  }))

  default = {
    us-east-1 = {
      app-type-1 = [
        "app1",
      ]
    }
    us-west-2 = {
      app-type-1 = [
        "app1",
        "app2",
        "app3"
      ]
    }
  }
}

// loop over map
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_configuration_template" "mytemplate" {
  depends_on = [aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.myapp]
  provider      = aws.us-west-2
  for_each = toset(var.beanstalk_applications["us-west-2"]["app-type-1"])
  name = "app-type1-base"
  application = each.value
  solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2015.09 v2.0.8 running Go 1.4"
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name = "VPCId"
    value = "blah"
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name = "Subnets"
    value = "blah"
  }
  // added this
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name = "ELBSubnets"
    value = "blah"
  }
}
```

When I add a new block terraform reorders the whole thing

```
+ setting {
    + name      = "ELBSubnets"
    + namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    + value     = "blah"
  }
- setting {
    - name      = "Subnets" -> null
    - namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc" -> null
    - value     = "blah" -> null
  }
+ setting {
    + name      = "Subnets"
    + namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    + value     = "blah"
  }
- setting {
    - name      = "VPCId" -> null
    - namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc" -> null
    - value     = "blah" -> null
  }
+ setting {
    + name      = "VPCId"
    + namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    + value     = "blah"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code for this resource:
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/98b8b848ca94031b20c3e626c9d40484e3af80de/aws/resource_aws_elastic_beanstalk_configuration_template.go#L42

The `setting` argument does not force a new resource, yes what you are seeing is a bit annoying but not harmful in any way.

```
  "setting": {
    Type:     schema.TypeSet,
    Optional: true,
    Computed: true,
    Elem:     resourceAwsElasticBeanstalkOptionSetting(),
    Set:      optionSettingValueHash,
  },
  "solution_stack_name": {
    Type:     schema.TypeString,
    Optional: true,
    ForceNew: true,
  },
```

A solution will be to replace the TypeSet with a type that will keep the given order, but there could be side effects...

---

You could try with a dynamic nested block, something like:

```
provider "aws" {
  region      = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_configuration_template" "mytemplate" {  
  for_each = toset(["app1", "app2"])
  name = "app-type1-base"
  application = each.value
  solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2015.09 v2.0.8"

  dynamic "setting" {
    for_each = toset(sort(["ELBSubnets", "Subnets", "VPCId"]))
    content {
      namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
      name = setting.value
      value = "blah"
    }
  }
}
```

that `toset(sort(["ELBSubnets", "Subnets", "VPCId"]))`
should keep them in order at all times

Comment: But then if I change the order will tf try to remove/add back settings? I thought foreach created a map of key=>values in the state unlike count which just creates an array. I was thinking each "setting" config block would be bound to its own key in the state and order of the config wouldn't matter. Maybe I'm conflating some things

Comment: Oh I also am now mixing a dynamic block with statically configured settings. So I have some settings blocks individually defined and also a dynamic block of settings as well- to specify regional settings and then loop over a map of shared settings all regions use

Comment: Sorry @red888 I'm not sure I follow your comments... `foreach created a map of key=>values` yes it does for resources but not for dynamic blocks _ _ _ but main point from my answer is: **The setting argument does not force a new resource** you might not like to see all those changes but it is perfectly fine